# the showdialog refocus effect custom call

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

Is there a way to let the form blink, like the ShowDialog when it loses focus?

When you call ShowDialog on a windows form and you try another action the form blinks for a few seconds and then focuses.

Is there a way to call that blinking action in a custom way?

Comment: Do you have your own custom form that you are displaying and you want it to blink?  Could you do something in the Deactivate event to set the Visible property on and off a few times in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern Int32 FlashWindowEx(ref FLASHWINFO pwfi);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct FLASHWINFO {
        public UInt32 cbSize;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public FLASHW dwFlags;
        public UInt32 uCount;
        public Int32 dwTimeout;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum FLASHW: int {
        // stop flashing
        FLASHW_STOP = 0x00,
        // flash the window title
        FLASHW_CAPTION = 0x01,
        // flash the taskbar button
        FLASHW_TRAY = 0x02,
        // flash the window title and the taskbar button
        FLASHW_ALL = 0x03,
        // flash continuously
        FLASHW_TIMER = 0x04,
        // flash until the window comes to the foreground
        FLASHW_TIMERNOFG = 0x0c,
    }

    public static void FlashWindow(IWin32Window form, int count) {
        FLASHWINFO pwfi = new FLASHWINFO();
        pwfi.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(pwfi);
        pwfi.dwFlags = FLASHW.FLASHW_ALL;
        pwfi.dwTimeout = 0;
        pwfi.hwnd = form.Handle;
        pwfi.uCount = (uint)count;
        FlashWindowEx(ref pwfi);
    }
```

Extend it for your needs.

Comment: The line FLASHW.FLASHW_ALL tells to flash the title bar of the form and also the task bar button. Use either FLASHW_CAPTION or FLASHW_TRAY to flash them seperately. Just try it out.